# Unable to merge android manifests while building APK in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality, google-vr

this error is shown while building APK in unity:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. 
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe -Xmx4096M
>   -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools"
>
> ### -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
>
> stderr[] stdout[ Warning:
>   [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:12,
>   C:\Users\pc\Documents\Sample4\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-keyboard\AndroidManifest.xml:3]
>   Main manifest has  but library
>   uses targetSdkVersion='24' Warning:
>   [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:12,
>   C:\Users\pc\Documents\Sample4\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-keyboardsupport-release\AndroidManifest.xml:3]
>   Main manifest has  but library
>   uses targetSdkVersion='24' Warning:
>   [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:12,
>   C:\Users\pc\Documents\Sample4\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-permissionsupport-release\AndroidManifest.xml:3]
>   Main manifest has  but library
>   uses targetSdkVersion='24' ] exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32,
>   IntPtr)

I added google vr package to the assets and I tried changing 3
manifest file in it(minimum SDK and target SDK part) but it doesn't
worked.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

```
Main manifest has {I dunno why nothing is printed}  but library uses targetSdkVersion='24' Warning:
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:12,
```

You should **change your app target sdk version to 24 or higher.**